# How to remove duplicates from combobox populated from column values in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

So far, I've managed to retrieve column values and populate a combobox with them using the following code:

ComboBox1.DataSource = DbdocsDataSet.dbdocs

ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "serie" '(serie is a column in my table)

The table is filled with books that can belong to the same series. So what I get with the code above is a combobox full of different multiplicated values.

Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: Prevention is pretty much always better than cure. Don't try to remove duplicates when you shouldn't be putting them in there in the first place. Fix your `DataSet` so that it has a query that will get the distinct values you want. Either that or don't bind that `DataTable` to the control but, instead, create a distinct list first and then bind that.

Comment: Also, don't set the `DataSource` before setting the `DisplayMember`. ALWAYS set the `DataSource` last.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome @HaraHeim ! You have 3 answers if one of them answered your question, accept that answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. This will earn you a few points and help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like youre using strongly typed datatables. Use the following code instead:

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(DbdocsDataSet.dbdocs.Select(Function(r) r.serie).Distinct().ToArray())
```

You don't need the display member, because this solution doesn't use binding. If you need to keep using binding, perhaps because you use ValueMember somewhere, consider:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = DbdocsDataSet.dbdocs_
 .GroupBy(Function (r) r.serie) _
 .Select(Function (g) g.First()) _
 .ToList()

ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "serie" '(serie is a column in my table)

ComboBox1.ValueMember = "..."
```

Do please rename your controls to something better after you add them to a form

Note, if valuemember is a particular item out of the serie group, you'll need to add code to make sure that the value you want is first (add an orderby before the `First()` )

---

I also echo the sentiement of not having duplicates in the first place. Add another query to the dataset's tableadapter, like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT serie FROM whateveryourtablenameis
```

And use that as your datasource

Comment: Yeah, you're right about correctly identifying controls. This was just something that came to my mind and started trying to make it work. In that context, I passed renaming the combobox =P

Comment: About the coding, I went with the last option. I've created a query in the tableadapter which worked perfectly in the wizard. However, I'm having trouble with the code:

cmbserie.DataSource = DbdocsTableAdapter.serielimp

This code gives me the following exception: Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource

What I'm missing?

Comment: A tableadapter is a device that pushes data back and forth between a database; it isn't a container of data itself. I'd have done something like: 1) Right click the design surface, 2) Choose Add.. TableAdapter, 3) Written a query like SELECT DISTINCT serie as Disp, serieId as Val FROM whateveryourtablenameis`, 4) called the queries `FillDistinctSerie` and `GetDistinctSerie` on the next page of the wizard, finish the wizard. Now I can do e.g. `myCombobox.DataSource = myDispValTableAdapter.GetDistinctSerie()` - it works because it returns a `datatable` which is suitable for binding

Comment: I recommended those column aliases because the same tableadapter etc can be used for other combos around the application, like suppose you have a list of CityName and CItyId, you can make another query on the same tableadapter, of `SELECT DISTINCT CityName as Disp, CityId as Val FROM CitiesWithDuplicates`, - the aliases mean that the cityname goes in the Disp column of the datatable etc, and then you can `cityCombo.DisplayMember = "Disp"; cityCombo.ValueMember = "Val"; cityCombo.DataSource = dispValTableAdapter.GetDistinctCities();` i.e. you're re-using the same datatables for different querys

Comment: You know, I have another exception now, but don't worry... I must tell you that I've started learning vb.net like two weeks ago... Maybe I have to keep learning and trying before attempting these kind of things...

Comment: The exception messages are usually pretty good; just search for the exact text and see what comes up. If I was going to learn anything I'd have started on c# mainly because most of the code samples you'll find in your VB life are c#, but contra to what many people think they're the same language underneath and concerting from one to the other is pretty easy if you just follow some basic rules

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at it

```
   Public Sub test()

      Dim dt As New DataTable

      dt.Columns.Add("serie")
      dt.Columns.Add("title")

      dt.Rows.Add("1", "2")
      dt.Rows.Add("1", "3")
      dt.Rows.Add("1", "2")

      'ComboBox
      cboTest.DataSource = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "serie")
      cboTest.DisplayMember = "serie"

   End Sub
```

^^

Comment: If you can't use .DefaultView.ToTable , you should remove duplicates from your query.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.totable?view=netframework-3.5

Comment: Ignoring the second parameter of .ToTable returns distinct rows. Which in your example would be 2 rows. The OP wants distinct serie.

Comment: cboTest.DataSource = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "serie")

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you can retrieve a DataTable or use Tables(0) from your DataSet then this should do what you want.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim lst = (From row In dt.AsEnumerable
               Select row.Field(Of String)(0)).Distinct.ToList
    ComboBox1.DataSource = lst
End Sub
```